# How to get MySQL case statement to work inside a stored procedure?

Tags: mysql, select, case

I'm trying to use the MySQL CASE statements to select products from a products table.

I have this:

```
SELECT art.a,art.b,art.c
FROM products AS art
   WHERE art.inventory != "0"
   # filter by param_reference_iln (seller ID = vARCHAR(13) )
   CASE        
    WHEN param_reference_iln = '3333333333333' THEN AND art.iln = '1111111111111' OR art.iln = '2222222222222'
    WHEN param_reference_iln = '8888888888888' THEN AND art.iln = '7777777777777'
    ELSE AND art.iln NOT IN ('1111111111111','2222222222222','7777777777777')
   END CASE;
```

I have tried both [CASE variants](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-statement.html), but I can't get either to work.

**Question**:
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Fix your query, several syntax errors. Missing `AND` in front of `CASE`, `THEN AND` is also not possible, maybe more...

Comment: What exactly you want to do if value of param_reference_iln is 3333333333333 or 8888888888888? What exactly you want to return from your query?

Comment: *can't get either to work* is not a valid MySQL error message.

Comment: I'm only starting with MySQL. Correcting syntax now. The query should give me product id (art.a), description (art.b) and price (art.c) of all products in the database that have inventory > 0. The case statement filter out my demo-accounts (ELSE ...NOT IN 111,222,333) or only show the demo products (Demo account 333 and demo account 888)

Comment: You have not tried this CASE variant - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/control-flow-functions.html. It differs from this one - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/case-statement.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you can have a CASE in a WHERE clause.
Anyway, you should use a strict boolean syntaxe here:

```
SELECT art.a,art.b,art.c
FROM products AS art
WHERE art.inventory != "0"
    AND (
        (param_reference_iln = '3333333333333' AND (art.iln = '1111111111111' OR art.iln = '2222222222222'))
        OR
        (param_reference_iln = '8888888888888' AND art.iln = '7777777777777')
        OR
        art.iln NOT IN ('1111111111111','2222222222222','7777777777777')
    );
```

Comment: THANKS! So much... I was going desperate looking how to get this to work.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use a `CASE` to dynamically construct a where clause by having it return conditional statements such as `THEN AND ...` and expecting the `AND` to apply to the preceeding condition

You need to use vanilla inline logic;

```
WHERE art.inventory != "0"
AND (
    (param_reference_iln = '3333333333333' AND art.iln IN ('1111111111111', '2222222222222'))
  OR  
    (param_reference_iln = '8888888888888' AND  art.iln = '7777777777777') 
  OR
    (art.iln NOT IN ('1111111111111','2222222222222','7777777777777'))
)
```

Comment: Ok. Understand. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

It's not for selects, but for stored procedures. Scroll down the page you posted and you will see

Comment: Sorry to mention, I'm trying this inside a storedproc. Edited the questions. Thx!